# Size of custom view for android notification

Tags: android, notifications

I want to change default android notification view. Can I make height of Custom Expanded View more than 3 lines of text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) on how to make custom notifications using your own layout. If this helps you already: good. If not: The [RemoteView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html) also offers options to create custom notifications, so it might help you. Alternatively you could create multiple notifications if the number of lines is really limited (which I am not sure of).