# Displaying customized notifications with custom height

Tags: android

I'm trying to show a notification with custom height. I'm using below codes to generate the notification, but it doesn't set the height correctly.

How should I change this code?

##########################################
The same question in Persian

##########################################
من می خواهم ناتفی کیشنی با ارتفاع دلخواه ایجاد کنم 

با استفاده از کد زیر ناتفی کیشن ایجاد میکنم 

کسی میتونه کمک کنه تا ارتفاع ناتفی کیشنو تغیرش بدم

```
      public static void notficate1() {
              int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
           long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
           Notification notification = new Notification(icon, "Custom Notification", when);

           NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getsrviso;

           RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(pname, R.layout.custom_notification);
           contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
           contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, "Custom notification");
           contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, "This is a custom layout");
           notification.contentView = contentView;

           Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(G.context, MainActivity.class);
           PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(G.context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
           notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;

          //notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR; //Do not clear the notification
           notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS; // LED
           notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;  Vibration
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND; // Sound


           mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Size of custom view for android notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130770/size-of-custom-view-for-android-notification)

Comment: Can you please mention what have you tried so far? There are already some SO [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130770/size-of-custom-view-for-android-notification) [dealing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033602/custom-notification-maximum-height) with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you have several styles of notifications. It's likely you need the `NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()` (documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded.html)).

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033602/custom-notification-maximum-height) you have a maximum height per style and [this conversation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/t79db8f0x2s) notes the size cannot be altered

Comment: I will catch up to explain the source!!